# Facebook audience network bidding integration

Tags: android, admob, ads, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I received this notification from facebook on my FAN account

[image: Move your apps to bidding]

```
Move your apps to bidding
You need to move your apps to bidding before the deadlines so they can continue monetizing with Audience Network
```

But I have no clue how to integrate bidding into my app. And it doesn't make any sense that they want us to move to open bidding but the available resources are vague and confusing. I clicked on the move apps to bidding button and in that selected my app and clicked next. There you will have the option to select the mediation partner (I selected No mediation platform Audience Network Only).

But then there was this card that said:

```
Follow integration instructions
To integrate bidding successfully, you'll need to use one of our mediation partners. See our mediation partners.
```

- What does it mean? I must choose one of the bidding partners inorder to integrate bidding? If so then why the heck there is an option for no mediation platform?

After that there is only one button on the screen that says Generate API Token.
It will basically generate API token that you will have to use on your selected mediation platform. Again, what if I don't have or want to use another mediation partner?

I selected no meadiation platform for a reason and now I have this generated API token that I don't know what to do with it.

I integrated Facebook Audience Network into my app. Adding the banner layout to the xml and then adding the code to initialize the ads in the activity. Now how do i integrate google admob with bidding integration ? Do I need to add google ADS sdk and then add their implementation (layout views and code etc.) I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: hey Vishal, it sounds like you're using AdMob. You can integrate Audience Network as a bidder to your AdMob setup following this - https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9234488?hl=en-GB

Comment: Hey did you managed to find any solution for the problem you mentioned in the last paragraph? Please provide an answer if so, I am facing the very same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is just removed faceboook audience network and added admob.
I did it using this video (This is in hindi). I coudln't find a guide about using facebook audience network and adding admob as mediation partner.

You can check the video if you want to setup admob and Facebook audience network as bidding mediation

[How to Move your Apps to Bidding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4jEwyfOXn0)